# Google Distance Matrix API's sending array and processing return to match ID

Tags: php, api

I have been asked to improve a system that currently has a customers address imputed into some form fields and when its submitted the system queries a database of suburbs that belong to staff against the customers address. It returns the km's and distance time for each staff members traveling time/distance so the person who submitted the request knows which staff member can get to that customer the quickest. Currently the system loops through each staff member 1 by 1. With each pass through it queries the google matrix api. With 45+ staff to loop through its taking anywhere from 15 to 35 seconds to return the whole list.

I have found a way to pass all the addresses through in one query to the google matrix api as a url and return an array. Its now down to less than 1 second and almost instant. An example request sent can be seen [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=NEW%20FARM%20Queensland%20Australia%7CCLAYFIELD%20Queensland%20Australia%7CHIGHFIELDS%20Queensland%20Australia%7CLOGANHOLME%20Queensland%20Australia%7CMORNINGSIDE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBURLEIGH%20HEADS%20Queensland%20Australia%7CCLEVELAND%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBUDERIM%20Queensland%20Australia%7CWELLERS%20HILL%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBRISBANE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CDARLING%20HEIGHTS%20Queensland%20Australia%7CRED%20HILL%20Queensland%20Australia%7CKIRWAN%20Queensland%20Australia%7CROCHEDALE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CPARADISE%20POINT%20Queensland%20Australia%7CCAMP%20HILL%20Queensland%20Australia%7CSURFERS%20PARADISE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CCOOMERA%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBROADBEACH%20Queensland%20Australia%7CSPRINGFIELD%20LAKES%20Queensland%20Australia%7CDAISY%20HILL%20Queensland%20Australia%7CKALLANGUR%20Queensland%20Australia%7CTRINITY%20BEACH%20Queensland%20Australia%7CSHERWOOD%20Queensland%20Australia%7CCRANBROOK%20Queensland%20Australia%7CNORTH%20WARD%20Queensland%20Australia%7CINDOOROOPILLY%20Queensland%20Australia%7CSUNNYBANK%20Queensland%20Australia%7CMOUNT%20LOFTY%20Queensland%20Australia%7CLABRADOR%20Queensland%20Australia%7CPALM%20BEACH%20Queensland%20Australia%7CNUNDAH%20Queensland%20Australia%7CEIGHT%20MILE%20PLAINS%20Queensland%20Australia%7CEVERTON%20PARK%20Queensland%20Australia%7CJIMBOOMBA%20Queensland%20Australia%7CGLADSTONE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBELLBOWRIE%20Queensland%20Australia%7CPACIFIC%20PINES%20Queensland%20Australia%7COONOONBA%20Queensland%20Australia%7CNORTH%20LAKES%20Queensland%20Australia%7CKANGAROO%20POINT%20Queensland%20Australia%7CURRAWEEN%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBARGARA%20Queensland%20Australia%7CTARINGA%20Queensland%20Australia%7CASPLEY%20Queensland%20Australia%7CBULIMBA%20Queensland%20Australia%7C&destinations=BRISBANE):

Problem I have now. Is each one of those origin suburbs was assigned to a staff member user. There is no way to send that staff members user id or unique identifier to googles api and in turn im not sure how to return each result and match it against the staff members suburb.

Does anyone have an ideas?

Im currently doing a curl request using php to generate that url and get the response from google matrix api in an array.

Comment: It looks like the order of results from google is the same as the order of origin points. It will be a simple matter of matching keys to figure out which results refer to which user.

Comment: i seriously hope it isnt that simple.. now that you mention it i cant believe i didn't think of that. ill have a go and let you know. Thanks  ;)

Comment: You were right @Scopey .... Took about 10 seconds to fix using the keys to compare. i did a function as per answer below.

Comment: please tell me the way to make that origins string and pass to google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed as per Scopey's suggestion by using key in both arrays and matching them.

```
function array_merge_custom($array1,$array2) {
    $mergeArray = [];
    $array1Keys = array_keys($array1);
    $array2Keys = array_keys($array2);
    $keys = array_merge($array1Keys,$array2Keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $mergeArray[$key] = array_merge_recursive(isset($array1[$key])?$array1[$key]:[],isset($array2[$key])?$array2[$key]:[]);
    }

    return $mergeArray;

}
```