# Laravel get distance between one location and array of locations google matrix

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

I asked this question many times but no answer, I want to get the driving distance between a customer and 50 stores using matrixapi from google, where I have the latitude and longitude of the customer, and array of latitude and longitude of every store with store id

```
       array:57 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 695
        "lat" => "2.9315257"
        "long" => "101.7638137"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 696
        "lat" => "2.9660291"
        "long" => "101.7499998"
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "id" => 700
        "lat" => "2.937143099999999"
        "long" => "101.7779784"
      ]
```

I used the url but hard to use it forloop so how can I pass the array and get the distance for every store with its id

```
     $distance_data = file_get_contents(
                'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.$from_latlong.'&destinations='.$to_latlong.'&key='.$googleApi
            );
       
              $distance_arr = json_decode($distance_data);
            $distance = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
            $duration = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
           
            $distance = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",  $distance);
            $duration = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",  $duration);
           
            $distance=$distance * 1.609344;
           
            $distance=number_format($distance, 1, '.', '');
            $duration=number_format($duration, 1, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to run this, but from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters), it seems that you should separate each set of co-ordinates with a `|`.

> **origins** — The starting point for calculating travel distance and time. You can supply *one or more locations separated by the pipe
> character (|)*, in the form of an address, latitude/longitude
> coordinates, or a place ID:

and

> **destinations** — One or more locations to use as the finishing point for calculating travel distance and time. *The options for the*
> *destinations parameter are the same as for the origins parameter*,
> described above

So this code loops over the destinations and creates a second array with the `x,y` values, then it `implode()` them with a `|`...

```
$dests = [[
        "id" => 695,
        "lat" => "2.9315257",
        "long" => "101.7638137"
        ],
        [
        "id" => 696,
        "lat" => "2.9660291",
        "long" => "101.7499998"
        ],
        [
        "id" => 700,
        "lat" => "2.937143099999999",
        "long" => "101.7779784"
]];

$coords = array_map(function($data) { return  $data['lat'].",".$data['long']; }, $dests );
$from_latlong = implode("|", $coords);
$distance_data = file_get_contents(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins='.$from_latlong.'&destinations='.$to_latlong.'&key='.$googleApi
        );
```

So the destinations will look something like...

```
2.9315257,101.7638137|2.9660291,101.7499998|2.937143099999999,101.7779784
```

Edit

From the extra code you've posted, it would be something like...

```
$distance_arr = json_decode($distance_data);
foreach ( $distance_arr->rows[0] as $key => $element )  {
    $distance = $element->distance->text;
    $duration = $element->duration->text;
    // The matching ID
    $id = $dests[$key];
    
    $distance = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",  $distance);
    $duration = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",  $duration);
    
    $distance=$distance * 1.609344;

    $distance=number_format($distance, 1, '.', '');
    $duration=number_format($duration, 1, '.', '');  
}
```

the `foreach` will loop through the elements and then `$key` will be the index if the element as well as the destination, and so you can pick out the ID from the matching element in the source array.

Comment: thank you so much, it seems we closed to slove this issue but how can I return the store id with every distance?

Comment: the resut of the destinations like this:  2.9919972,101.7908387|2.967131,101.790345|2.9803211,101.7545648|2.961915,101.757051|2.9619076,101.7567725|2.952091,101.778178|2.9632235,101.7539941|2.9602035,

Comment: Is that the result from the API or just `$from_latlong`?

Comment: you did great job for me, it is working fine just need to get id for every store with the result   "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "0.9 mi",
                  "value" : 1494
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "4 mins",
                  "value" : 211
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "elements" : [

Comment: Does it return an array of the results, you may be able to match the position of the result using the position in the `rows` array to match it up.  If you want to add the JSON coming back to the question I can try and solve that part.

Comment: this is the json  $distance_arr = json_decode($distance_data);
                $distance = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
                $duration = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
but how to store them with ids?

Comment: I would assume that as you have `elements[0]`, then it would be (from my test code) `$dests[0]['id']`, this assumes that the 1st element matches the first destination.  You will need to check that though.

Comment: can you please explain more? or add it in your solution? I tried from here with the function of array1 array2 but didnt work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928252/google-distance-matrix-apis-sending-array-and-processing-return-to-match-id

Comment: Can you add the content of `$distance_data` to the question (along with the distance data) and I can have a go.

Comment: check please and I really appreciate your help

Comment: Trying to get property 'distance' of non-object

Comment: is it should be like this  $distance = $element[0]->distance->text; but this forloop for one row?

Comment: it should be 
foreach ( $distance_arr->rows as $key => $element )